# Outbound WebSocket connection from Docker container does not work

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, websocket

I have a simple TypeScript program running on Docker, and this program would like to open a Websocket connection to an outside Websocket server. Something like this

```
-----------------------                   ------------------------------
| My Local Docker     |                   | my.ws-server.somewhere.com |                   
|                     |                   |                            |
|    WS client        |---> Internet----->| WS server                  |
-----------------------                   ------------------------------
```

When I run (`ts-node test.js`) the code with the WS client on my dev environment outside Docker, it works fine and can connect without any issues:

```
let ws = new WebSocket("ws://my.ws-server.somewhere.com", [], { })
ws.onopen = () => {
  console.log('Connection opened ok! ')
}
```

However, when I put this some thing inside Docker and run it there, the connection is refused. The program starts the connection attempt as it should, but there is just a timeout and the connection is never opened. I guess this has something to do with Docker network? If I want to open an outbound connection from Docker to the outside world, do I need to define some routes or something?

My Docker setup

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.18.3

RUN mkdir /src

WORKDIR /src
ADD ./package.json /src/package.json
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  my-service:
      container_name: my-service
      restart: always
      build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: my-service.dockerfile
      volumes:
          - ".:/src"
```

(I noticed that I can make this work by adding `network_mode: "host"` to docker compose, but that's not what I would really want to do so that I could keep the normal inbound port mappings)

Comment: did figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check if your websocket is opened on the good port, I see you expose port 3000. Also you must check if your proxy is well set up for the port. It could be also possible that you need a secure websocket connection to make it work (then the url becomes wss://mywebsocket.something.com).

Give me Feedback when you can

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I tried to expose port 80 (port in mywebsocket.something.com) also but it didn't help. In general, should I expose also all outgoing ports? Also, wss is not required. As I mentioned, when I run the code outside Docker, it works perfectly fine. Connects without any problems. But when I put the code inside docker and run it from there, then it doesn't connect anymore.

Comment: Also, I can rule out any possible errors at mywebsocket.something.com. I get the same result using ws://echo.websocket.org. I can connect there with exact same code when it is run outside Docker, but connection fails if the same code is run from inside Docker. However, when I create a test WS server on my host (outside Docker) can I connect to it from Docker with address like ws://docker.for.mac.localhost:4101. So connection to ws://docker.for.mac.localhost:4101 works from docker, but connection to ws://echo.websocket.org (or to any other external service) doesn't work

Comment: Also what is interesting is that the problem seems to be just with WebSockets. I can make a REST call to outside world without any problems (like request('http://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {...) from inside the docker. No problem. But opening a Websocket from inside the docker to the outside world doesn't work.

Comment: And even more interesting: connection to ws://echo.websocket.org doesn't work from Docker, but connection wss://echo.websocket.org does work from Docker. So for some reason ws doesn't work, but wss works.